# H2O Exception TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'unicode'

Tags: h2o

On Linux, H2O 3.16.0.2 - Exception occured while running GBM with hyperparameter search.

The below information is about H2O and its giving exception.

- H2O cluster uptime:         3 hours 17 mins
- H2O cluster version:        3.16.0.2
- H2O cluster version age:    1 month and 4 days
- H2O cluster name:           beast
- H2O cluster total nodes:    1
- H2O cluster free memory:    25.46 Gb
- H2O cluster total cores:    32
- H2O cluster allowed cores:  32
- H2O cluster status:         locked, healthy
- H2O connection url:         http://localhost:54321
- H2O connection proxy:
- H2O internal security:      False
- H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
- Python version:             2.7.12 final

  gbm Grid Build progress: [################################################] 100%
  Errors/Warnings building gridsearch model

  Hyper-parameter: col_sample_rate, 0.44
  Hyper-parameter: col_sample_rate_change_per_level, 1.03
  Hyper-parameter: col_sample_rate_per_tree, 0.38
  Hyper-parameter: histogram_type, QuantilesGlobal
  Hyper-parameter: max_depth, 4
  Hyper-parameter: min_rows, 128.0
  Hyper-parameter: min_split_improvement, 1e-06
  Hyper-parameter: nbins, 256
  Hyper-parameter: nbins_cats, 512
  Hyper-parameter: sample_rate, 0.55
  failure_details: None
  failure_stack_traces: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at hex.Model$Parameters.read_unlock_frames(Model.java:322)
      at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:209)
      at hex.ModelBuilder.trainModelNested(ModelBuilder.java:262)
      at hex.grid.GridSearch.startBuildModel(GridSearch.java:332)
      at hex.grid.GridSearch.buildModel(GridSearch.java:314)
      at hex.grid.GridSearch.gridSearch(GridSearch.java:213)
      at hex.grid.GridSearch.access$000(GridSearch.java:68)
      at hex.grid.GridSearch$1.compute2(GridSearch.java:135)
      at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1263)
      at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
      at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
      at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
      at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
      at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "malware_detection.py", line 167, in 
    validation_frame = valid_split)
    File "/home/beast/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  /h2o/grid/grid_search.py", line 189, in train
  self.build_model(parms)
  File "/home/beast/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages   /h2o/grid/grid_search.py", line 204, in build_model
  self._model_build(x, y, training_frame, validation_frame, algo_params)
  File "/home/beast/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  /h2o/grid/grid_search.py", line 250, in _model_build
  failure_messages_stacks += error_message+'\n'
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'unicode'
  H2O session _sid_af98 closed.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem and can't find out what the problem is. did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is particularly frustrating because it waits until after training all models to generate this error.

It was happening to me after running one grid search, changing hyperparameters, then doing a second grid search. Somewhere online saw a way to append new grid search results to old ones, but short of that, restarting h2o got it at least working again for me:

```
h2o.cluster().shutdown()
h2o.init()
```